# Duplicate entries in EF7 join table for many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm following the core ef-mvc tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model) and I have a two models that share a many-to-many relationship with each other, which means that I have to have a one-to-many relationship defined between both these classes and a class that's used exclusively for the join table, right?  ie.

```
public class JoinTable    
{
  public int model1ID;
  public model1 model1;    
  public int model2ID;
  public model2 model2;
}
```

In the example DbInitializer seed method, this code:

```
foreach(Enrollment e in enrollments)
{
       var enrollmentInDataBase = context.Enrollments.Where(
        s =>
            s.Student.ID == e.StudentID &&
              s.Course.CourseID == e.CourseID).SingleOrDefault();
       if (enrollmentInDataBase == null)
       {
            context.Enrollments.Add(e);
       }
}
```

Essentially saves all entities defined in the seed method that don't already exist in the table.  How could I write a method that will save the entity to the database up to x amount of times (I need this capability for my own app)?  Also based on my knowledge, I'm certain that there is an implicit restriction in the data model (or table) definition that would have to be altered?

Comment: Are you saying you want to have multiple entries of the same row in the table?

Comment: Precisely.  If you remember my data model had classes Deck, and Card.  I'm using a class DeckCard now as join table but each Deck should be able to use each cardID up to 3 times.  So the join table would need to allow for multiple entries of the same row.  I thought adding an ID to the DeckCard class would make each row uniquer but I still get an exception.

Comment: Lol 'uniquer'.  That's 100% a typo...  This is why you proofread.

Comment: @Forklift You're beautiful...

Comment: I added a 'Count' property to the DeckCard class and having identical Card and Deck ID's still throws an exception even with different Count values.

Comment: I think you'll only want 1 entry for each card and the count will be how many of that card is in the Deck. Either that or you'll want (instead of Count), something like InstanceNumber. Then you'll want to make sure there is no unique constraint that forces only one DeckId/CardId entry. It might be helpful to ask another question with updated examples of your code and current issues.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice; will do.  You basically answered my question.  Should I answer it myself with my updated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments, but moving here for visibility:

You want to have a third property in DeckCard called Count with only 1 entry for each card and the count will be how many of that card is in the Deck.